# Add php variable to JQuery UI diaglog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

How do I add php variable to Jquery UI dialog modal box,
for instance I have a form that has contain information's to be inserted in database, when user click the submit button the insert query will execute and once successful I will have JQuery UI modal box appear on page and ask user if they want to insert new items, but how do I redirect the page with php value?

this is my actual link that modal box needs to redirect: home/purchase_order_pricing?**code=eGx8t6gc2SI7**

here's my code:

```
$code = $this-input->post('code');

<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script src='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( '#dialog-confirm' ).dialog({
    height: 50,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    dialogClass: 'no-close success-dialog',
buttons: {
'Yes': function() {
 window.location = 'home/purchase_order_pricing?code = $code';
},
No: function() {
$( this ).dialog( 'close' );
}
}
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='dialog-confirm' title='Add more items?'>
<p>asd</p>
</div>
<div id='popup-msg'>
    <div id='loading'>
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
        <h3>Please wait a few seconds.</h3>
    </div>  

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the php variable to the javascript like this:

```
<script>
var code = "<?php echo $code; ?>";
</script>
```

and the you can use the variable `code` in your javascript. Is that what you need?
For example:

```
window.location = 'home/purchase_order_pricing?code =' + code;
```